# Launch IE or other browser in kiosk mode across multiple monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, browser, internet-explorer, html

Presenting an exhibit on a video wall consisting of 6-monitors, I need to launch a browser full-screen across all monitors to display HTML content.

On a single monitor, I know browsers such as Internet Explorer can use the "-k" parameter to launch in kiosk or full-screen mode:

```
iexplore.exe -k [path]
```

But this launches the browser on a singular display.

All monitors are attached to one computer with a bridged graphics card supporting 8-independent displays via 8-DVI outs.

Clearly I can stretch the browser across all displays manually by resizing the window; however, I'm looking for an automated full-screen mode in which address bar / tabs / any chrome of the browser is hidden.  Only the page content should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen setups where the driver handles all connected displays as a single virtual displays. That way your application could use it completely.
Otherwise the application or at least the window manager needs to be multimonitor aware and capable.
I would try the virtual single display approach first.